# Is that make sense atomic for MoveNext in async generated StateMachine

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

Recently, I am reading Eduasync serial in [Jon Skeet’s blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/default.aspx). When I read in [part 7](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/05/20/eduasync-part-7-generated-code-from-a-simple-async-method.aspx), one question blocked me, I thought the C# generated statemachine may not work properly in some rare case, let’s deep in code(this code is from Jon Skeet's Eduasync part 7, I just add some commends):

```
public void MoveNext() 
{ 
    int result; 
    try 
    { // doFinallyBodies is never used 
        bool doFinallyBodies = true; 
        if (state != 1) 
        { 
            if (state != -1) 
            { 
                task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => 5); 
                awaiter = task.GetAwaiter(); 
                // In a rare case, in this moment the task still has not completed, 
                // so return false IsCompleted
                if (awaiter.IsCompleted) 
                { 
                    goto Label_GetResult; 
                } 
                state = 1; 
                // The task just completed before OnCompleted, 
                // but in this moment we haven't call the OnCompleted yet, 
                // so the task's ContinueWith is nothing the task will complete 
                // without ContinueWith and we will never get back to this StateMachine again.
                doFinallyBodies = false; 
                awaiter.OnCompleted(moveNextDelegate); 
            } 
            return; 
        } 
        state = 0; 
      Label_GetResult: 
        int awaitResult = awaiter.GetResult(); 
        awaiter = new TaskAwaiter<int>(); 
        result = awaitResult; 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        state = -1; 
        builder.SetException(e); 
        return; 
    } 
    state = -1; 
    builder.SetResult(result); 
} 

public struct TaskAwaiter<T>
{
    private readonly Task<T> task;

    internal TaskAwaiter(Task<T> task)
    {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public bool IsCompleted { get { return task.IsCompleted; } }

    public void OnCompleted(Action action)
    {
        SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        TaskScheduler scheduler = context == null ? TaskScheduler.Current
            : TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        task.ContinueWith(ignored => action(), scheduler);
    }

    public T GetResult()
    {
        return task.Result;
    }
}
```

So do you think this could be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure I understand you correctly, I'll describe the sequence of events I think you're expecting in more detail:

1. The asynchronous operation is started
2. `IsCompleted` is checked, which will return `false`, because the operation didn't finish yet
3. The operation completes
4. `OnCompleted()` is called, which in turn calls `ContinueWith()`, but because the `Task` has already completed, the continuation is never executed

If I got this correct, then your mistake is in step 4. That's because the authors of `Task` were aware of this race condition, and so if you call `ContinueWith()` on an already completed `Task`, the continuation *will be scheduled immediatelly*. Because of that, the state machine will work correctly even in this situation.

Unfortunately, [the documentation for `ContinueWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696) isn't very clear about this (it explains when the continuation *won't* be scheduled, but not when it will).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly I want to ask. Thank you for your answer, it makes sense for me. By the way, can you provider more about ContinueWith() "will be scheduled immediatelly" except the MSDN document.

Comment: That just means the `Task` will be added to the current `TaskScheduler`. It's then up to the scheduler when will it be executed. Is that what you were asking?